Is it safe to remount the filesystem root / as read-write?
To clarify: I know that basically any root access is unsafe. But I'm asking only about the remount command itself, not about what can happen after.
I want to execute as root something like:
mount -o rw,remount /

Can this particular command or its equivalent theoretically break something (especially my data or even the whole OS) or I only need to be careful after the execution?
P.S. I use Termux as terminal emulator and KernelSU as root solution, but I don't think these things matter

Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve

@RohitGupta I'm trying to achieve exactly what the title says (remount /), nothing more

I am not sure I understand the question... Just remounting a filesystem read-write can't "break" anything unless you actually write something to it. Can a mount/remount command damage anything? Nope, not if done correctly. I can't really put this as an answer as I have no definitive reference, but it's kind of like asking if you write someone an email but don't send it, will they get it... No, not unless you take some additional action.

@acejavelin I kind of disagree. See the quote, in this question// Surely things have changed a lot from then but it was at least a concern

@beeshyams Interesting... I had not heard that before. I guess my answer assumed that the root (or temp root) was already accomplished, which should have already triggered the tampered flag. Not sure how you would mount system r/w without root access which already implies the system has been modified.
